# Send data from server to a client (Raspberry Pi) without pull request

Tags: sockets, raspberry-pi, client-server

I have a Raspberry Pi and I am developing an application on the Pi that can be controlled by a web portal.

So I need to know, if I change something in my website, how will that be transferred to my Pi which is a client without any pull request from the client.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to install Apache on your Raspberry and setup a basic http PHP or Python API. When a change is posted on the website, the back-end script makes a API call to the Raspberry API service.

If you are using PHP as your web server, you could use json_decode(file_get_contents(...) to access the Raspberry API.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use Websockets.

Websockets are bidirectional and client and server can communicate whenever they want as TCP session is ongoing. So, yo will not need to do polling.

You can download and compile [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org/) for your raspberry as server or as I did in one of my previous projects, you can install [nodejs](http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/) into the raspberry and use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) library to handle all. Of course, you will need to do some modifications in your web page to behave like [websocket client](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) or [socket.io client](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/).

Good luck!